# Derivative of function w.r.t to vector where matrix elements are functions itself

Tags: matrix-calculus

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ with

$$
f(r) = ||Ap - b||_2^{2} = p^{\top}A^{\top}Ap - 2p^{\top}A^{\top}b + b^{\top}b
$$

where

- $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ and  $p,b \in \mathbb{R}^N$
- The elements of the matrix $A$ are linear functions of the variables $r = (r_1, \ldots, r_N)$, i.e.
  $a_{i,j} : \mathbb{R}^{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $A = (a_{i,j}(r_1, \ldots, r_N))_{i = 1, \ldots, N, j = 1, \ldots, N}$.
- I know the partial derivatives of each matrix element, i.e. $ \frac{\partial a_{i,j}}{\partial r_k}$ is known.

Is there any chance for a closed form of $\nabla f$? Any hints or help is really appreciated!

PS: This question is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3425863/derivative-of-a-matrix-with-respect-to-a-scalar-variable). But there the matrix depends only on one variable.

Comment: If "$A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$" then "The elements of the matrix A" cannot be (non-constant) functions.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Hm, more precisely, the elements are linear functions. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
X,Y &\in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n} \\
X:Y &= {\rm Tr}(X^TY) = {\rm Tr}(Y^TX) = Y:X \\
}$$
or in terms of components
$$\eqalign{
X:Y &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m X_{ij}Y_{ij}
 \qquad&\big({\rm explicit\,summation}\big) \\
    &= X_{ij}Y_{ij}
 \qquad&\big({\rm Einstein\,convention}\big) \\
}$$
The colon product can also be applied to vectors by setting $m=1$ and treating them as rectangular matrices.

The following matrix will turn out to be useful
$$G = 2\left(Ap-b\right)p^T$$

Use this product to write the function and calculate its differential
$$\eqalign{
 f &= (Ap-b):(Ap-b) \\
df &= 2(Ap-b):(dA\;p) \\
   &= 2\left(Ap-b\right)p^T:dA \\
   &= G:dA \\
}$$
Switch to index notation and substitute the known derivative
$\;H_{ijk} = \left(\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial r_k}\right)$
$$\eqalign{
dA_{ij} &= H_{ijk}\,dr_k \\
df &= G_{ij}\,H_{ijk}\,dr_k \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r_k} &= G_{ij}\,H_{ijk}
  &\big({\rm gradient\,wrt\,}r\big) \\
}$$
or, using explicit summations, the components of the gradient are
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r_k}
 &= \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N G_{ij}
    \left(\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial r_k}\right) \\
}$$